# Searching the Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch, redux, flux

We **fetch** `posts` and store them in the Redux store.

We **select** (and maybe filter) `posts` out of the store and display them in components.

```
store: {
    posts: {
        entities: {
            posts: { ... }
        },
        result: [...]
    }
}
```

---

If we fetch some `posts` through a text query e.g. *"Posts about redux"* place them in the store and then later **select** them out again... How do we do that?

There are many `posts` now in the store, some of them are from our matched *search* and some are from other fetch requests.

Its easy to filter the store by parameters such as `{ createdAt, authorId, categoryId }`, but a text search is different as its matching many fields and the logic for this search lives on the server in ElasticSearch or similar technologies.

We do not want to reimplement this search logic on the client side again...

#### QUESTION:

> How do we select items from the Redux store, that were stored via a search query?

Comment: It sounds like you're storing all posts in the same place; you'll need to store them separately from other posts or implement search logic for processing (searching) stored posts.  One solution would be to have a separate reducer call for fetching the "selection" posts a selector will return.  Do you have a selector for the current set of viewed posts, you can make a reducer set the collection of posts you want to see (the search results)?

Comment: So you are suggesting that i store anything filtered by a `{ query }` search in a different state slice from all the other posts?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it.  You'll want to manage storage limits if you're allowing more than one query to persist at a time.

Comment: That seems backwards, as i would need to reimplement ALL my selectors again for the extra location posts are stored in.

Comment: You don't have one set of "selected" posts for viewing?

Comment: We store all posts in one state slice, we use selectors to filter and pick posts out of the store and display them in components. No, we don't store "selected" or "filtered" posts in our store.

Comment: Maybe you could create two separate mechanisms:
1. When a user searches, call the search API and only return the id's of the posts that are in the search result
2. When the result is returned from the server, do a request to the server to retrieve the data for all the posts that are not already in the redux store.

You could even further optimise by storing the result from the search API in the redux store. So if a user performs the same search multiple times you could pull the result from redux. The need for this depends on how often that occurs though.